# How to get tar and caulking off brick?

Tags: concrete, brick, roofing, masonry, polish

What's the best method for removing dried tar and caulking from brick and getting the brick's surface flat again?

I have a rotary polisher and thought maybe a disc of some kind would work.

[image]

Comment: Sandblasting, maybe?

Comment: @keshlam That's not an option (legally) in my area.

Comment: Wire brush, then?

Comment: Are you sure you don’t want to just paint that with a nice new coating? Or flash over it? Removal seems like (a) work, and (b) potentially damaging to the brick.

Comment: Do you know what was adhered there, and why? You might want to consider replacing it.

Comment: Unless your flashing work is incomplete, I'd be more worried about the interface between the chimney and shingles, as there are huge unsealed gaps there that will let a lot of water inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a chisel and scrape the bulk of the material off the bricks. then get a portable grinder to finish off the smoothing process. You can usually rent them at your home store if you don't have one. I doubt you will be able to safely mount a grinding disk to your rotary polisher.

Comment: Thanks @JACK. Any disc type in particular I should look for to out on the grinder?

Comment: @eclipsis A [Diamond Cup Grinding Disc](https://www.google.com/search?q=diamond+cup+grinding+disc) should do the job nicely.

Comment: Thanks @brhans!

Comment: I think I'd consider a flap wheel before using a diamond cup wheel.